# price calculation from custom field (woocommerce)

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

i have create custom field in single product page in woocommerce where user can input value height and width respectively, as input value displays in cart and checkout page too. Example: if user input height='15' and width='20' then its display is cart page like height=15 width=20

[image: single product page custom field]

[image: custom field in cart page]

now what im trying to achieve is that calculate height and width with formula to get final price,final price which should be update in cart as well as checkout page

total price = (height/3 * width/30 + 3)*1.48

im unable to achieve this section or i dont know how to achieve this

the code so far i have tried

```
/*
 * Display input on single product page
 * @return html
 */
function kia_satish_option(){
    $value = isset( $_POST['_satish_option'] ) ? sanitize_wp_checkbox( $_POST['_satish_option'] ) : '';
    printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_satish_option" value="%s" type="number"/>', __( 'Height', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_satish_option', 9 );

function kia_satisher_option(){
    $value = isset( $_POST['_satisher_option'] ) ? sanitize_wp_checkbox( $_POST['_satisher_option'] ) : '';
    printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_satisher_option" value="%s" type="number"/>', __( 'width', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_satisher_option', 9 );


function kia_yard_option(){
    $value = isset( $_POST['_yard_option'] ) ? sanitize_wp_checkbox( $_POST['_yard_option'] ) : '';
    printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="_yard_option" value="%s" type="number"/>', __( 'yard', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_yard_option', 9 );



/*
 * Add custom data to the cart item
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @param int $product_id
 * @return array
 */
function kia_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['_satish_option'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['satish_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_satish_option'] );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['_satisher_option'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['satisher_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_satisher_option'] );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['_yard_option'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['yard_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_yard_option'] );
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'kia_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );


/*
 * Load cart data from session
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @param array $other_data
 * @return array
 */
function kia_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values['satish_option'] ) ){
        $cart_item['satish_option'] = $values['satish_option'];
    }

    if ( isset( $values['satisher_option'] ) ){
        $cart_item['satisher_option'] = $values['satisher_option'];
    }

    if ( isset( $values['yard_option'] ) ){
        $cart_item['yard_option'] = $values['yard_option'];
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'kia_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2 );





/*
 * Add meta to order item
 * @param int $item_id
 * @param array $values
 * @return void
 */
function kia_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

    if ( ! empty( $values['satish_option'] ) ) {
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'satish_option', $values['satish_option'] );           
    }

    if ( ! empty( $values['satisher_option'] ) ) {
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'satisher_option', $values['satisher_option'] );           
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'kia_add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );




/*
 * Get item data to display in cart
 * @param array $other_data
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @return array
 */
function kia_get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['satish_option'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'height', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['satish_option'] )
        );

    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['satisher_option'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'width', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['satisher_option'] )
        );

    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['yard_option'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Yard', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['yard_option'] )
        );

    }

    return $other_data;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'kia_get_item_data', 10, 2 );


i tried to achieve formula section by code below

    function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save($post_id)
{
    $woocommerce_product_height = $_POST['_product_height'];
    $woocommerce_product_width = $_POST['_product_width'];
    $woocommerce_final_price = $_POST['_final_price'];


// calculate and save _product_area_price, _regular_price, price as Height*Width
    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_height) && !empty($woocommerce_product_width)))
        $woocommerce_final_price = $woocommerce_product_height * $woocommerce_product_width ;
```

but this code seems to be total not related with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just on this too recently.

So save the dimensions data using the `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter. I see you are only taking in 2 arguments. If this is variable product, you'll need all 4 params in the filter.

Then we do the pricing override. You can't use `woocommerce_add_to_cart` to do the pricing override as the product data doesn't get carried over to the session cart. You need to use the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook to iterate through the cart contents and change the product price.

This code is taken directly from this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324605/change-cart-item-prices-in-woocommerce-version-3-0

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10, 1);

function add_custom_price( $cart_obj ) {
//  This is necessary for WC 3.0+
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
    $value['data']->set_price( 40 );
    }
}
```

To elaborate a little, check out the `class-wc-cart.php`'s `add_to_cart()` method to see what is stored each content item. Basically the `$value['data']` in the above code is the product you are storing foreach product. You want to check `$value['your_custom_info_key']` that you set previously in that item data filter to get your custom info, where `your_custom_info_key` should not be any of the following as these are used by WooCommerce itself.

```
'key'          => $cart_item_key,
'product_id'   => $product_id,
'variation_id' => $variation_id,
'variation'    => $variation,
'quantity'     => $quantity,
'data'         => $product_data,
```

Comment: really appreciate your help as problem have been solved.......this may helpful for variable products....